# How many n-bit strings are unbalanced?

Tags: bit-strings

I am stuck on this question that i came across in my assignment. What does it mean by unbalanced string? I don't know the proper approach of solving this question

How many n-bit strings are unbalanced?

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-an-unbalanced-bracket-sequence-to-a-balanced-sequence/

Comment: Your source should contain a definition, but if I had to guess, then I'd say a *balanced* binary string had an equal number of $0's$ and $1's$.  Though [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-all-possible-n-length-balanced-binary-strings/) we see a more refined definition for the term.